# Android build at bitbucket pipelines failing for task app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease

Tags: android, gradle, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to build my repo with Bitbucket pipelines but it is failing. The repo has dependencies on other repositories so I am cloning them at runtime and clone happens successfully but at the end of the `assembleRelease` task, it fails.

pipelines.yml is below.

```
image: mingc/android-build-box:latest

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - cp my_key ~/.ssh/id_rsa
          - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
          - cp config ~/.ssh/.
          - chmod 400 ~/.ssh/config
          - chmod +x gradlew


          - git clone dependencies repos
          - ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

It throws below exception

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
* Try:
Run with --debug option to get more log output.
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:84)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:54)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:158)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:173)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:163)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:123)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:76)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexTransform.transform(DexTransform.java:443)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:178)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:174)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:156)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at com.android.builder.core.DexByteCodeConverter.dexOutOfProcess(DexByteCodeConverter.java:210)
    at com.android.builder.core.DexByteCodeConverter.runDexer(DexByteCodeConverter.java:159)
    at com.android.builder.core.DexByteCodeConverter.convertByteCode(DexByteCodeConverter.java:146)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.convertByteCode(AndroidBuilder.java:1386)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexTransform.transform(DexTransform.java:272)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at com.android.builder.core.DexByteCodeConverter.dexOutOfProcess(DexByteCodeConverter.java:206)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessInfoBuilder$JavaProcessInfoImpl.getExecutable(ProcessInfoBuilder.java:349)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.buildProcessException(GradleProcessResult.java:74)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:49)
```

I have enabled multidex too and sometimes occasionally build runs successfully but generally fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some struggle was able to fix it. The issue was with the size of Pipeline container which is fixed at 4GB and in my dex config I had also configured it to grab 4GB which was causing the error. Later I reduced it to 3GB and then it worked like charm.